# How to insert a data of type Date in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, date

I want to insert date in a table with type Date not String ( as I have to sort it later). I can't use function put() of content values because it takes only (String, String) arguments, not date. So how can I insert the current date of the system in a table row? Help Please.

```
 public long createEntry (String name, String db_dr, int amount, Date dt){
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues ();``
            values.put(DbOpenHelper.ENTRY_NAME,  name );
            values.put(DbOpenHelper.DR_CR, db_dr );
            values.put(DbOpenHelper.ENTRY_AMOUNT, amount);
            values.put(DbOpenHelper.DATE, dt); // function put defined for (string, string)
            long insertid= database.insert(DbOpenHelper.TABLE_ENTRIES, null, values);
            return insertid;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite [doesn't support a Date datatype](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime). What you could do, instead, is store the date in Unix time. If the date is stored in a `Calendar`, use `getTimeInMillis`, for example.

Comment: I used Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() and it stored: 1366494816221. How can I get date in the format DD-MM-YY or in any other format similar to that? thank u in advance

Comment: @IvaKodhelaj It depends on what you want to do. You can use `DateUtils` if you need this as a String displaying a date. You can throw this into `Calendar.setTimeInMillis()` so you can later use `Calendar.get()` to get a particular date.

Answer (score 0):

you can insert the date as milesecond. As your comment says you were able to store the date using milis and facing problem to retreive it and convert it to date. Here is an example

```
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(date_in_milis);
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int date = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

It will set the year, months, date and day as integer. So by some calculation you can format as a string if you want to get month/day name also.